# Ввод текста на javascript без тега input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Для игры, написанной с помощью Javascript, html5 нужно вводить имя игрока для сохранения его прогресса. У меня есть функция отрисовки диалога:

```
function drawDialog() { // функция отрисовки диалога
    ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0 + iBgShiftY, 700, 700, 0, 0, 700, 700);
    drawGradient();
    if (iDialogPage === 4) {
        ctx.fillText("Enter name:", ctx.canvas.width/2 - 150, ctx.canvas.height/2 - 110);
        //здесь нужна форма для ввода имени игрока
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

На canvase лучше рисовать только gameplay, всё остальное на html лучше.